# adapter replacement for 12V 0.5A

Tags: dc, adapter

Can I use a 12V DC 1.0A adapter in place of a 12V DC 0.5A adapter for my piano keyboard? The keyboard comes with a 12V DC 0.5A adapter but it is lost. I found a 12V 1.0A and wanted to know if it can be used. I don't want to use this adapter if it might harm the electronics.

Comment: canonical thread on the subject of power supply power ratings: [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/34745/7036)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, yes.

There are a couple of things that you need to look out for.

1) Does the connector match up?  Both the size and polarity matter here.

2) Is your new power adapter a SMPS unit or just a plain-old iron-core unit?  The difference is that the SMPS version has a regulated output whereas the iron-core unit will often have an output voltage that is significantly higher than the nameplate rating when used at lower than full output current.

You can usually tell them apart just from the size and weight.  A iron-core power adapter weighs 4 or 5 times as much as the newer SMPS version.

Comment: Thanks! I plugged it in just now and it works great. I called Guitar Center and they said it would work as long as amps were same or more as old adapter. So 1. polarity matches 2. a SMPS unit. Thanks for answering so FAST.